# How to select only some children in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have some divs in my HTML, a dynamic number of divs

How to select only divs 2,5,8,11 ?

I tried this `:nth-child(2n+3)` but is not exactly what I need

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <style>
          .a:nth-child(2n+3) { background:#ff0000; }
      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p class="a">The first paragraph.</p>
    <p class="a">The second paragraph.</p>
    <p class="a">The third paragraph.</p>
    <p class="a">The fourth paragraph.</p>
    <p class="a">The fifth paragraph.</p>
    <p class="a">The sixth paragraph.</p>
    <p class="a">The seventh paragraph.</p>
    <p class="a">The eight paragraph.</p>
    <p class="a">The ninth paragraph.</p>
    <p class="a">The seventh paragraph.</p>
    <p class="a">The eight paragraph.</p>
    <p class="a">The ninth paragraph.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why don't you use classes?

Comment: show us your html code, so we can se what you got

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wJehb


i nedd only paragraphs 2,5,8,11......etc

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**EDIT** If Only 2,5,8,11 is needed then the answer would be:

```
p:nth-child(3n+2)
{
   background: #ccc;
}
```

---

To select paragraphs 2, 3, 5, 8, 11:

```
p:nth-child(3n+2),p:nth-child(3)
{
   background: #ccc;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/uXR2G/)

I had to add p:nth-child(3) separately because it doesn't fit in the general pattern of +3 each time.

Comment: He says  2, **3**, 5, 8, 11

Comment: p:nth-child(2),p:nth-child(3n+2)
{
    background: red;
}

Comment: Well, you're right, so either the question's wrong or his comment ;)

Comment: is my mistake, i dont need children 3

Comment: firstly, don't add <br/> between paragraphs use css for that eg margin-bottom:10px ... but if you must use it then change nth-child to nth-of-type eg p:nth-of-type(3n+2)
{
    background: #ccc;
}

Answer (score 1):

E:nth-child(n)  an E element, the n-th child of its parent

For example :

```
 div:nth-child(2),div:nth-child(5){color:red;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the divs are being inserted dynamically could you not give each div an id like 'nested1, nested2' etc? If you use this approach remember not to start your id with an integer as CSS won't pick it up.